# Monitor Outlook's indexing feature?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm using Outlook 2010, and I need to find all emails that match a keyword.

I get the message:

> Search results may be incomplete because items are still being
>   indexed. Click here for more details.

When I click on it I'm told that there are 50,000 items still waiting to be indexed...

Is there any way to monitor the indexing process and get a notification when it's done? Other than clicking on the yellow message every five minutes?

Answer (score 4):

Since Outlook 2007 and 2010 use the windows indexer, you can go to the Indexing Options (In windows 7 type "indexing" in the "super bar") in windows and it will tell you at the top of the window the current status of your index, including the status of your outlook index.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or use Google Desktop Search to index your Outlook email.

It tells you when the initial indexing is done (which can take several hours), after that it just auto-indexes everything. Searching all your emails is instant. In my previous job I used to be able to find any email sent or received in the preceding 10 years, and find it within 1 minute.